# Segmented Sort with CUDPP/Thrust

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust, cudpp

Is it possible to do segmented sort in with CUDPP in CUDA? By segmented sort, I mean to sort elements of array which are protected by flags like below.

```
A[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

Flag array[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
```

Sort elements of A which are between consecutive 1.
Expected output

```
[9,10,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: If you can enumerate the ranges a little differently, [this method](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/thrust-users/BoLsxO6b4FY) may be of interest.

Comment: Which means there is no direct method available in Thrust/CUDPP?

Answer (score 6):

you can do this in a single sorting pass: the idea is to adjust the elements in your array such that sort will relocate elements only within the "segments"

for your example:

```
A[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
flag[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
```

(I removed the first 1 since it's not needed)

first scan the flag array:

```
scanned_flag[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
```

then you have many options depending on the number types, e.g. for unsigned integers you can set the highest bits to distinguish the "segments".
The easiest way is just to add the largest element multiplied by scanned_flags:

```
A + scanned_flag*10 = [10,9,18,17,16,25,24,23,22,21]
```

the rest is easy: sort the array and reverse the transformation.
Here are the two versions: using Arrayfire and thrust. Check whichever you like more.

Arrayfire:

```
void af_test() {
 int A[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};  
 int S[] = {0, 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0};  
 int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(int);

 af::array devA(n, A, af::afHost);
 af::array devS(n, S, af::afHost);
 // obtain the max element
 int maxi = af::max< int >(devS);

 // scan the keys
 // keys = 0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2
 af::array keys = af::accum(devS);

 // compute: A = A + keys * maxi
 // A = 10,9,18,17,16,25,24,23,22,21
 devA = devA + keys * maxi;

 // sort the array
 // A = 9,10,16,17,18,21,22,23,24,25
 devA = af::sort(devA);

 // compute: A = A - keys * maxi
 // A = 9,10,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5
 devA = devA - keys * maxi;
 // print the results
 print(devA);
}
```

Thrust:

```
template<typename T>
struct add_mul : public binary_function<T,T,T>
{
add_mul(const T& _factor) : factor(_factor) {
}
   __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const 
{
    return (a + b * factor);
}
const T factor;
}; 

void thrust_test()
{
  int A[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};  
  int S[] = {0, 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0};  
  int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(int);
  thrust::host_vector< int > hA(A, A + n), hS(S, S + n);

  thrust::device_vector< int > devA = hA, devS = hS, keys(n);
  // scan the keys 
  thrust::inclusive_scan(devS.begin(), devS.end(), keys.begin());
  // obtain the maximal element
  int maxi = *(thrust::max_element(devA.begin(), devA.end()));
  // compute: A = A + keys * maxi
  thrust::transform(devA.begin(), devA.end(), keys.begin(), devA.begin(), add_mul< int >(maxi)); 
  // sort the array
  thrust::sort(devA.begin(), devA.end());
  // compute: A = A - keys * maxi
  thrust::transform(devA.begin(), devA.end(), keys.begin(), devA.begin(), add_mul< int >(-maxi)); 
  // copy back to the host 
  hA = devA;
  std::cout << "\nSorted array\n";
  thrust::copy(hA.begin(), hA.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach might be that the range of values in `A` might be too big to get multiplied by their segment numbers. On the other hand, it is fast. Another possible way is to do a stable sort by keys and then stable sort by segment numbers. The disadvantage is that it involves a lot of data movement, while your method moves items only locally inside of the individual segments, which might be very beneficial on a GPU if the segments are smaller than workgroups of the sorting kernel (then the sorting efficiently takes place in local memory).

Comment: But other than that, interestingly, the complexity of sorting the full sequence is the same `O(n)` as sorting the segments individually, since radix sort is used. Except that sorting the segments individually may require fewer passes of the radix sort thanks to the lower key bit width (if true segmented sorting was implemented).

Comment: If the data type is of size 32, you could also sort the array of type u64 which will just be

`scanned_flag<<32 | A`. That way you do not need to worry about the range of intermediate values.